# What is a kutikan?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is a kutikan as relates to trailhead amenities?

> "We'll be adding amenities to complement the MUT like benches, water fountain, and a kutikan." Source: a proposal report for the Missouri River in Kansas City, Missouri. Not online.

> "It is proposed that the existing Class II Trailhead at Quanah Parker Park be upgraded to a Class I by adding a kutikan, drinking fountain, and related trailhead amenities." Source: a proposal report for the Trinity River in Fort Worth, Texas. https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/43744104/neighborhood-and-recreational-enhancement-plan-trinity-river-

> "A Class I Trailhead includes: A parking lot, picnic tables and shelter, an enclosed restroom, trash cans, trail signage, water/dog fountains, nominal electrical outlets, dog bag dispensers, benches and a bike rack. Class I Trailheads may possibly have boat launches, (Example - White Settlement Class I Trailhead on Page 46) Source: https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/43744104/neighborhood-and-recreational-enhancement-plan-trinity-river-

> A Class II Trailhead includes:
> A parking lot, possible picnic tables/shelter, dog bag dispensers, trash cans, a water fountain and trail signage (Example - SH 183 Class II Trailhead on Page 30)" Source: https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/43744104/neighborhood-and-recreational-enhancement-plan-trinity-river-

Comment: There is just one google hit for "[upgraded to a Class I by adding a kutikan](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/43744104/neighborhood-and-recreational-enhancement-plan-trinity-river-)" The 'kutikan' itself is possibly a proprietory name for some product. My guess is some kind of "nice looking" garbage disposal.

Comment: What region of the world did you find this in? That does not look like a normal English word, but rather some invented or imported term that did not originate in any Germanic or Romance language.

Comment: MUT and Quanah Parker Park would seem logical places to enquire. But the word is almost certainly non-standard.

Comment: Subtracting Class II amenities from Class I gives an enclosed restroom, extrapolating to kutikan, cutie can, or porta-potty.

Comment: @EllieKesselman Given that  Quanah Parker Park is in Texas, I don't think the word is Indonesian.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен People who speak the Indonesian language go camping in Texas too.

Comment: @YosefBaskin The only usage of cutie can [given by Google is in Myamar](https://www.facebook.com/CandiesMyanmar/videos/cutie-can/478920325949798/).  Good idea though, and maybe there are more specialist references to it as a euphemism for portable toilet!

Comment: @YosefBaskin Perhaps a can on the QT is one that's silent but deadly.

Comment: @tchrist I found a LOT of porn on Google when I searched for "cutie can" verbatim.

Comment: @veloeddy can you provide sources for these quotes?

Comment: Added sources and locations.

Comment: Thanks. I guess. Yumpu is possibly the worst user interface I’ve ever encountered!

Comment: @EllieKesselman agree with the idea that people who speak Indonesian can go on holiday in Texas, but why would there only be one word in Indonesian? I'm not sure what you mean about the U.S. National Geospatial-Intelligence Agency.

Comment: The absence of any answer from the people highly knowledgeable about the language strongly suggests that the term is a part of some idiosyncratic jargon used by the people developing the Trinity River recreational enhancements. The most effective way of finding out what they meant by the term would be for somebody to contact them and **ask them**; that would make much more sense than the contributors to this site trying to guess what they may have meant. Contacting them with that question may also help them realize that the term is incomprehensible to anybody outside their circle.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен I was trying to communicate EXACTLY what jsw29 commented! Apparently I failed to do so in my answer, however jsw29 is entirely correct in my opinion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it pertains to a specific usage of a word from another, not-English language (Indonesian) for the purpose of one small company's product advertising.  See second to last comment on the question.